# How do I access the contents of a .tsv file with React and papa-parse?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

Here is my App.js in the react app:

```
import FileUpload from './components/file-upload'

const App = () => {

  return (
          <div>
             <FileUpload />
          </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my FileUpload component:

```
import Papa from "papaparse"

const FileUpload = (props) => {
    return (
        <main>
            <div id="fileDrop"

                onDragOver = {(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                }}
                onDrop = {async(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    let dataArray = []

                    const data = await Object.values(e.dataTransfer.files).map( file => {
                        if (file.type === "text/tab-separated-values") {
                            const text = file.text()
                            text.then(text => {
                                const parsed = Papa.parse(text, {delimiter: "\t"})
                                parsed.data.forEach(row => {
                                    dataArray.push(row)
                                    return row
                                })
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    // console.log 1
                    console.log(data)
                    // console.log 2
                    console.log(dataArray)
                    // console.log 3
                    console.log(dataArray[0])
                }}
            >drag here</div>
        </main>
    )
}

export default FileUpload
```

The problem I'm running into is I can't seem to get access to the data from the .tsv file after I drop it. When I try to map over it and console.log the returned array (console.log 1), they just say undefined, and when I push it to dataArray and console.log that (console.log 2), I can click into it and all the data is there, but when I try to access an individual key (console.log 3), it says undefined again.

Am I using async/await correctly? Is it a problem with the file.text() promise?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping over each file value first and `filter` out any files that you don't need instead of using the `if` statement. Then `map` over each file and call `file.text()`. This will return a `Promise` for each file.

With [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you can wait for all of the promises to resolve before continueing. Now it makes sense to use `await` as `Promise.all` also returns a promise (`Object.values` does not return a promise so awaiting it has no effect).

When all promises resolve you should end up with an array of texts. Loop over each text with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). The reason for doing this over a regular `map` is that `Papa.parse` returns an array of rows. `flatMap` will flatten the array of arrays to a single array of rows, as seemed the intention with the code in the question.

```
const texts = await Promise.all(
  Object.values(e.dataTransfer.files)
    .filter(file => file.type === "text/tab-separated-values")
    .map(file => file.text())
);

const dataArray = texts.flatMap(text => {
  const parsed = Papa.parse(text, {delimiter: "\t"});
  return parsed.data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful. I guess I need read up more on promises and async/await. :)